# Swift: Google Translate Format fails

Tags: ios, json, swift, google-translate

and thanks for checking this question out.

Here's my problem, I'm trying to create a simple Google Translate application. I've already activated it in Google Console so I'm thinking my problem is with my code.

The format returned is

> {  "data": {   "translations": [    {
>       "translatedText": "bonjour",
>       "detectedSourceLanguage": "en"    }   ]  } }

My code is setup like this:

```
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        var task = session.dataTaskWithURL(transURL){
            data, response, error -> Void in
            NSLog("dkc 1")
            if(error != nil){
                println(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            var jsonError : NSError?
            NSLog("dkc 2")
            var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &jsonError) as Dictionary<String, String>
            NSLog("dkc 2.5"
            if (jsonError? != nil){
                println(jsonError!.localizedDescription)
            }
            NSLog("dkc 3")
            if let apiDelegate = self.delegate?{

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                    NSLog("dkc 4")
                    apiDelegate.didFinishGTTranslation(jsonResult)
                }

            }
```

Sorry for the bad formatting... I'm not sure but I think the problem is on the var jsonResult line how I'm setting the return type to "as Dictionary". The response is a little more complex than that but I'm just not sure how to set it up.

When I run the program it stops on the line mentioned above (jsonResult) and goes to the swift_conformsToProtocol setting

0x10c210572:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
0x10c210580:  movq   %rax, -0x108(%rbp)
0x10c210587:  xorps  %xmm0, %xmm0

#### 0x10c21058a:  movaps %xmm0, -0x70(%rbp)

0x10c21058e:  movq   $0x0, -0x60(%rbp)
0x10c210596:  movq   (%rdx), %rax
0x10c210599:  cmpq   $0x41, %rax

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I am trying to user your code in my project what did you put as transURL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cast your top level JSON object as `<String:String>` while in fact it is `<String:AnyObject>`, the value of your top level dictionary being another dictionary.